# How can I know which is the lastest Python version compatible for Tensorflow v2.x?

Tags: python, tensorflow

As title. My requirement is very simple. Since I will probably need to use the latest features of Python at my work. I wonder how to know the latest version of Python can be used with Tensorflow v2.x without any trouble regarding compatibility. I must put emphasis on that I need to use the `tensorflow.keras` module. I don't want to get an error message during the model training. Any advice?

I did try to follow the issue on their GitHub on supporting Python3.9. While the issue is closed, most of the comments there are **NOT** from the contributors/maintainers. And the last comment is on 2021/6. Is Python3.9 the lastest compatible version to run Tensorflow v2.x?

Comment: Have you tried looking at [their install guide which lists the supported python versions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install)? Or does it have to be specifically version 2.0 rather than the latest 2.x (in which case, [pip has the answer: 2.7 & 3.4 - 3.7](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.0.4/))?

Comment: @GPhilo: Yes I mean version >=2.0, let me update my question.

Comment: @GPhilo: For example, I need to use `tensorflow.keras` module. Are you sure there won't be any compatibility issue?

Comment: What's a "compatibility issue"? On its own, it's not a meaningful term. All versions of Tensorflow (as in, the specific 2.X build for python 3.7 vs the one for 3.10) are equivalent and they can interoperate (models trained in one work in the other without any concern). If you mean "Will I be able to run models trained with older versions of the library", the answer is in TF's release notes and is not related to python.

Comment: @GPhilo: Great, that's what I meant, thank you! If you have time this can be a very good answer(, while my question is quite vague, sorry)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorFlow 2 is supported from Python 3.7 to 3.10 according to their website: https://www.tensorflow.org/install?hl=en

Comment: Does it satisfy "without any trouble regarding compatibility?"

Comment: For example, I need to use `tensorflow.keras` module. Are you sure there won't be any compatibility issue?